# Idangerous swiper dynamically change mode

Tags: jquery, slider, swiper.js

I have trouble with it. I want to change mode of my swiper from 'horizlontal' to 'vertical' dynamically (for example when pressed the button). But I don't have a clue how to do it!
I tried to use `topSwiper.param('mode', 'vertical')` and `topSwiper.params.mode = 'vertical'` like it was said in API, but it doesn't work. Maybe someone have an idea on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it simple way - just make `topSwiper.destroy()` before initializing new `topSwiper` with new options.